# Windows 10, resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a serious problem with the interpretation of css in my browser. I tried most of the solutions available here and on the internet. I Checked regedit, my header section and other...
All the time I get an error `resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream` . I tried on IE, Opera, Chrome, Firefox. I work on Windows 10 64bit,RubyMine IDE and  I try run a simple html with external file SCSS.

My test html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/buttons.scss" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<h2>CSS Buttons</h2>
<button class="success_button"> Button </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Scss file:

```
// buttons

.success_button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I don't think you can serve `.scss` files directly to the browser.  It has to be compiled down to `.css` for the browser to parse/understand it.  You can either compile to `.css` in a build job as you develop or deploy, or I believe there is a way to have the server parse the SCSS before serving it up.  But I *believe* that is the issue-- the browser is getting a file with the wrong extension and isn't really sure what to do with it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You were right! It seems that it is ok.

Comment: Finally, I used the grunt to compile .css files from .scss. Everything works.

Comment: Congratulations! It's very satisfying to get those build jobs working properly!

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander mentioned, it requires being compiled down to css. However, how does one go about converting from scss to css you might ask? Here's what I found works after several failed attempts at different routes.

Simply visit the directory storing the scss file in your terminal, and type:

```
sass --watch filename.scss:filename.css
```

NOTE: This is "watching" for changes to filename.scss, so you may have to do an arbitrary save for it to pick up "changes".

After a short time, it'll complete and auto-populate filename.css (along with filename.css.map) in the same directory. This is the .css file you want to upload to your server.